# How to style the Paper-radio-button to a normal radio button?

Tags: html, css, polymer, polymer-1.0

For paper-input there is an alternative to make it normal design. That is iron input. Is there any alternative like that for radio button for making it as look like normal radio button? If so kindly help me..

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't look possible. The `<paper-radio-button>` is composed of `<div>`s (it doesn't wrap a native radio button) and only provides a limited set of CSS properties to customize colors and sizes. The CSS properties don't allow disabling the Material Design.

Consider using the native radio button with `iron-input` instead:

```
<input type="radio" is="iron-input">
```

```js
HTMLImports.whenReady(() => {
  Polymer({
    is: 'x-foo'
  });
});
```

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+1.7.1/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
  <link rel="import" href="iron-input/iron-input.html">
</head>
<body>
  <x-foo></x-foo>

  <dom-module id="x-foo">
    <template>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" is="iron-input">
        option 1
      </label>
    </template>
  </dom-module>
</body>
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/rjMEOe?editors=1000)